# Text not changing to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I currently have:

```
    $('.tweet').text(function (_, text) {

        var exp = /(#(\S+))/g;

        return text.replace(exp, '<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/search/%23$2">
                                      `$1 
                                  </a>'
                           );  

    });
```

This create the essentially something like:

`<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/search/%23data">#data </a>`

but it still displays as text and not a link.

Image example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

If you use `.text()`, your HTML will be escaped:

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(), which replaces special characters
>   with their HTML entity equivalents (such as `&lt;` for <).

[jsFiddle Example with `.html()`](http://jsfiddle.net/H8Lmx/)

Answer (score 3):

The jquery function `.text()` is the same as the javascript property [`.innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) / [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent).

Try '`.html()`' instead of '`.text()`'.

Comment: Thanks buddy pretty much the same answer as Bazmegakapa, he beat you to the punch by 4 minutes. +1

Comment: There is no `innnerText()` function. It is a property. Google on what it does exactly.

Comment: you're right. It exists only '.innerText' and '.innerHTML'. I'm sorry.